# Receive output from a batch file and input

Tags: c#, batch-file, textbox, console, output

I'm currently creating an application in C# that allows you to create a server and manage it easily, to do this it uses batch files to run said servers. It works by creating batch files and using those to run the server. (Java by the way).

So, what I'm wondering is if it's possible to grab the output from the console and rather than dumping it in a textbox and closing the console like the code below does, I need it to continually post any output from the console without closing and without spamming loads of consoles open (tried using a timer).

```
 Process myProcess = new Process();

        ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo =
            new ProcessStartInfo(batchfilelocation);
        myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
        myProcess.Start();

        StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;

        // Read the standard output of the spawned process.
        string myString = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();


        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + myString;

        myProcess.Close();
```

I'm also wondering if it would be possible to allow input from a windows forms control such as a button that would execute a command by entering it in the console and pressing enter for example. Or a textbox that allows you to do the same thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a TextBox control to store a string. Just use a string variable instead.

```
string concatenatedString = null;

concatenatedString += myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Secondly, you can do this without creating a console window. The code below will allow your program to run without seeing a ton of console windows popup.

```
myProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help! The textbox is now receiving everything from the console. However, is there any way to allow users to input commands to the console from a windows form control?

Comment: Actually, for some reason it's only receiving everything from the console once the console has closed?

Comment: Fixed it! Using a listbox now and running the jar rather than the batch file. Thanks for the help and sorry for all these comments. One last question, is there a way I can invoke the console that is running in the background to send commands to it?

Comment: Look into SendKeys.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx


Maybe that will work for you.